# Java 8 stream group by with multiple aggregation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to group my stream and aggregate on several fields

i.e.

```
private class Row {
    private String sku;
    private int colA; // sum
    private int colB; // sum
    private int colC; // avg
}
```

Example

```
  sku   colA    colB    colC
 ---------------------------
ar5sg5h  4       3       4
sd6ad6d  2       5       3
ar5sg5h  6       5       6
sd6ad6d  5       6       3
sd6ad6d  3       7       3
```

Expected:

```
 sku    colA    colB    colC
---------------------------
ar5sg5h  10      8       5.0
sd6ad6d  10     18       3.0
```

I already have `List<Row> rows`, where I have intention to **reduce** rows with **groupBy** and **aggregation** of sum on colA and colB where as average on colC.

How can I achieve this with **groupBy** + **multiple** **aggregation** using **Java-8** **stream**?

Comment: Can you also add few example with what you have and what is your expected output?

Comment: @miiiii Added to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to:

```
List<Row> result = rows.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Row::getSku))
        .values().stream()
        .map(e -> new Row(e.get(0).getSku(),
                e.stream().mapToDouble(Row::getColA).sum(),
                e.stream().mapToDouble(Row::getColB).sum(),
                e.stream().mapToDouble(Row::getColC).average().getAsDouble()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: the type int is not helpfull in your case, I would suggest to change it to double as the average is not `int`.

Outputs

```
Row(sku=sd6ad6d, colA=10.0, colB=18.0, colC=3.0)
Row(sku=ar5sg5h, colA=10.0, colB=8.0, colC=5.0)
```